# Python for-loop with generator expression worth it for already existing dictionary?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, generator-expression

I have a simulator program that does a lot of looping through all the objects in an existing dictionary. The dictionary includes several hundred thousands objects, and each of them has functions and attributes.

I was wondering how the speed/memory tradeoffs are for creating a generator expression for each loop, and if this is any better than simply looping through the values in the dictionary. For many of the loops there will also be an if-statement inside the loop.

**Example with simple for-loop and if-statement:**

```
for obj in dict.values():
    if obj.attr or n.state=='value':
        obj.someFunction()
```

**Example with generator expression:**

```
for obj in (n for n in dict.values() if n.attr or n.state=='value'):
        obj.someFunction()
```

So what I'm really wondering: Is it any point creating a generator here? Or does this only take more time and add complexity, since the dictionary already exists in memory?
I have done some testing of the time used, and it seems like the difference is negligible for this program, so what I'm most interested in is the possible memory usage.

Comment: Have you tried testing with `perf_counter`?

Comment: I have not, however I have done some simple tests with `timeit`, and the time difference is not much to speak about. Will update the question to reflect this!

Comment: I would expect this to be slightly slower, and to have no space benefits, ( how could it?). And the first approach is the most readable/idiomatic. Your generator expression simply *loops over the dict anyway*, so how could it be faster?

Comment: Using a loop+generator versus just a loop will always have an overhead, if merely by having the additional generator object to create/store/iterate. What makes you think there could possibly be an advantage in adding a generator for this?

Comment: So to answer your questions, "Is it any point creating a generator here?" No, there is no point.  "Or does this only take more time and add complexity, since the dictionary already exists in memory?" It adds overhead. The time and space complexity are the same, but it is pointlessly making this slightly slower.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I realise that this might have been a stupid assumption, but I thought that maybe the more lazy evaluation of the generator expression would help on memory usage and possibly speed.

Comment: @helge but think about it, how could it help? As you already intuited, you are just iterating over a container that already exists in memory, lazy evaluation doesn't help there

Comment: @helge Iteration via a ``for`` loop is already lazy. You can think of a generator as first-class iteration – pointless if you already iterate. Generators are useful to *pass around* iteration, which you don't need here.

Answer (score 1):

There is no advantage at all to using a generator like this. Both variants need to iterate on `dict.values()`, both need to filter via `if n.attr or n.state=='value'` – the generator only *adds* an overhead for the generator object itself and the additional, inner iteration.
While this overhead is small there is literally no advantage.

Choose the explicit `for` statement with `if` statement. It is better both for performance and readability.